# Make all possible combinations of list elements - using python

Tags: python

I am trying to make all the possible combinations of a list. 
like:

```
l= [1,4,6,8,11,13]

combL = [ [1],[4],[6],[8],[11],[13],[1,4], ..  ]
```

I tried to use

```
itertools.combinations(l, len(l))
```

but it didn't work out. Any function on Python that do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371887/making-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making all possible combinations of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371887/making-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from itertools import combinations

def get_all_combinations(input_list):
    for i in xrange(len(input_list)):
        for item in combinations(input_list, r = i + 1):
            yield list(item)    

input_list = [1,4,6,8,11,13]
for item in get_all_combinations(input_list):
    print item
```

We have created a generator, so it is efficient as we don't have to store the entire combinations in memory. It is important for a combinations generator, because, often the number of combinations is very big.

But if you want to get all the combinations as list, then you can do

```
list(get_all_combinations(input_list))
# [[1], [4], [6], [8], [11], [13], [1, 4], [1, 6], [1, 8], [1, 11], [1, 13],..]
```

Answer (score 1):

as a list:

```
[i for j in xrange(len(l)) for i in itertools.combinations(l, j+1)]
```

or as a generator:

```
(i for j in xrange(len(l)) for i in itertools.combinations(l, j+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res = []
for L in range(0, len(l)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(l, L):
        res.append(list(subset))
```

Output:

```
[[], [1], [4], [6], [8], [11], [13], [1, 4], [1, 6], [1, 8], [1, 11], [1, 13], [4, 6], [4, 8], [4, 11],....
```