# python all possible permutation using recursion

Tags: python, string, recursion

How can I implement the recursive way to write the permutation of an string?
For example, if the input is `'abc'`, I want my result to be:

```
[a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'ba',
 'bb','bc', 'bd', 'be', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc', 'cd', 'ce', 'da', 'db',
 'dc','dd', 'de', 'ea', 'eb', 'ec', 'ed', 'ee', 'aaa', 'aab', 'aac',
 'aad','aae', 'aba', 'abb', 'abc', 'abd', 'abe', 'aca', 'acb',
 'acc'....]
```

In addition, if a string from the result is also contained in an another list, then return that string. For example `'a'` and `'b'` are in `[a,aaah,aahed,aahing,aahs,'b']`, I want to display the `'a'` and `'b'`.

**Edit**

I tried to use a for loop, but I get a `MemoryError`.

```
def perm(l,last,result)
    if len(result[-1]==len(l)):
        return result
    else:
        for i in l:
            for u in last:
                last.append(u+i)
         result.extend(last)
    perm(l,last,result)
    return result

perm(['a','b','c'],[''],[''])
```

Comment: Can you make an attempt first? You are more likely to get help if you do.

Comment: What effort did you make?

Comment: @paisanco Hi, I just edit my questions to my efforts.

Comment: @kurenaiKunai I takes me a while to figure out how to type codes on stack overflow. I have edited my questions to include my codes.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371887/making-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-in-python][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate all strings of the *current* length and then look for longer strings recursively.

```
def perm(chars, prefix):
    result = []
    if len(prefix) < len(chars):
        for char in chars:
            result.append(prefix + char)
        for char in chars:
            result.extend(perm(chars, prefix + char))
    return result

print perm(["a", "b", "c"], "")
```