# Python all combinations of a list of lists

Tags: python, list, tuples, combinations, python-itertools

So I have a list of lists of strings

```
[['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]
```

and I want to get all possible combinations, such that the result is

```
[['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f'],
 ['a','b','c','d'],['a','b','e','f'],['c','d','e','f'],
 ['a','b','c','d','e','f']]
```

So far I have come up with this code snippet

```
input = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]
combs = []
for i in xrange(1, len(input)+1):
    els = [x for x in itertools.combinations(input, i)]
    combs.extend(els)
print combs
```

largely following an answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371887/making-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-in-python).

But that results in

```
[(['a','b'],),(['c','d'],),(['e','f'],),
 (['a','b'],['c','d']),(['a','b'],['e','f']),(['c','d'],['e','f']),
 (['a','b'],['c', 'd'],['e', 'f'])]
```

and I am currently stumped, trying to find an elegant, pythonic way to unpack those tuples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the tuple of lists into a list. Example -

```
import itertools
input = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]
combs = []
for i in xrange(1, len(input)+1):
    els = [list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x)) for x in itertools.combinations(input, i)]
    combs.extend(els)
```

---

Demo -

```
>>> import itertools
>>> input = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]
>>> combs = []
>>> for i in range(1, len(input)+1):
...     els = [list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x)) for x in itertools.combinations(input, i)]
...     combs.extend(els)
...
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(combs)
[['a', 'b'],
 ['c', 'd'],
 ['e', 'f'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
 ['a', 'b', 'e', 'f'],
 ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']]
```

Comment: Nice. I am often amazed at how powerful `itertools` is.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One idea for such a goal is to map integers from `[0..2**n-1]` where n is the number of sublists to all your target element according to a very simple rule:
Take the element of index k if `(2**k)&i!=0` where i runs over `[0..2**n-1]`. In other word, *i* has to be read bitwise, and for each bit set, the corresponding element from *l* is kept. From a mathematical point of view it is one of the cleanest way of achieving what you want to do since it follows very closely the definition of the parts of a set (where you have exactly `2**n` parts for a set with n elements).

Not tried but something like that should work:

```
l = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]                                                    
n = len(l)
output = []
for i in range(2**n):
    s = []
    for k in range(n):
        if (2**k)&i: s = s + l[k]
    output.append(s)
```

If you don't want the empty list, just replace the relevant line with:

```
for i in range(1,2**n):
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all combinations, you may consider this simple way:

```
import itertools

a = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]
a = a + [i + j for i in a for j in a if i != j] + [list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a))]
```

Comment: If the original list contained 4 lists, this would not contain the resulting combinations of length 3, though.

Comment: @Matt M. Yes, you are right, I did not consider the list contains 4 lists, only show a simple case. in case of more than 3 lists, Anand S Kumar's method will be the one you need. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

With comprehension lists :

```
combs=[sum(x,[]) for i in range(len(l)) for x in itertools.combinations(l,i+1)]
```