# How to find possible combinations of a string by substituting characters in the string using a dictionary?

Tags: python

I'm trying to find all possible combinations of a string while substituting some characters in the string using a dictionary. I have to accomplish this goal without importing any modules. Here is an example:

```
myDict = {'R':'AG', 'Y':'CT', 'M':'CA', 'G':'G', 'D':'ATG', 'A':'A'}

myString = "ARD"
```

So I want to write out all the possible combinations of myString using the above dictionary which should be `"AAA","AAT","AAG","AGA","AGT","AGG"`

I can't figure out how to iterate for each characters in the string and then put them in a list or something.

Comment: Please edit your post to include an explanation of how `ARD` turns into each of those six strings

Comment: use list(myString), then you can use itertools.combinations,   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371887/making-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-in-python

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 1):

IMO OP's description is a little bit vague but clear enough.

it sounds like a simple interview question to test the skill of recursion. See the answer (assume no duplication in `myDict`'s values)

```
results = []
def recr(str, pos):
    for w in myDict[myString[pos]]:
        if len(myString) - 1 == pos:
            results.append(str + w)
        else:
            recr(str + w, pos + 1)
recr('', 0)
print results
```

Screen output:

```
['AAA', 'AAT', 'AAG', 'AGA', 'AGT', 'AGG']
```

Comment: Wow, you decrypted the OP :-). Your `recus` should be `recr`, though.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @stanleyli for mind-reading the OP.

```
>>> map(''.join, itertools.product(*map(myDict.get, myString)))
['AAA', 'AAT', 'AAG', 'AGA', 'AGT', 'AGG']
```

Comment: Great! Thanks so much for your answer! I will try this today!