# How do I iterate through combinations of a list

Tags: python, list, iterator

I have a list of elements, say

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and I would like to iterate through couples of distinct elements of this list, so

```
for x, y in some_iterator(list):
    print x, y
```

should show

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
```

Note that I don't want all combinations of `list` as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8371887/3128109). Just the combinations of a given length.

What would be the most pythonic way of doing this ?

---

What if I wanted to do the same with n-uples ? For instance with combinations of `3` elements out of `n`

```
for x, y, z in another_iterator(list):
    print x, y, z
```

would show

```
1 2 3
1 2 4
2 3 4
```

Comment: The previous duplicate closure was inaccurate; I have corrected it.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

for combo in combinations(lst, 2):  # 2 for pairs, 3 for triplets, etc
    print(combo)
```