# subsets a set of distinct integers, nums, return all possible subsets python

Tags: python, sorting, backtracking

For example,
If nums = [1,2,3], a solution is:

```
[
  [3],
  [1],
  [2],
  [1,2,3],
  [1,3],
  [2,3],
  [1,2],
  []
]
```

My code is following:

```
class Solution(object):

"""
:type nums: List[int]
:rtype: List[List[int]]
"""
def subsets(self, nums):
    if not nums or len(nums) == 0:
        return 


    nums.sort()

    subset = []
    results = [[]]
    self.subsetHelper(nums, 0, subset, results)

    return results

def subsetHelper(self, nums, startIndex, subset, results):
    # subset is 1D list store elements that create results
    # results is 2D list that store results created

    results.append(subset)

    for i in range(startIndex, len(nums)):
        subset.append(nums[i])
        # recursion:
        self.subsetHelper(nums, i+1, subset, results)
        # backtracking:
        subset.pop()
```

While the answer of [1,2,3] suppose to be :

```
[[],[3],[2],[2,3],[1],[1,3],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
```

My answer is :

```
[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
```

Can somebody tell me where did I go wrong, and how to modify it in order to get `[ [3], [1], [2], [1,2,3], [1,3], [2,3], [1,2], [] ]`

Thanks.

Comment: You can use itertools for this

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your case is that **lists** are **mutable**.

To explain mutability briefly and how it is causing the problem, consider the following code -

```
x = something # mutable type
x = y
print x
# some statement that operates on y
print x # might print something different
```

Now in our case, an element in `result` can be considered analog to `x` in above example and `subset` as `y`'s analog. So, doing changes in `subset` makes changes in `result.

**Solution -**

Well, since our problem is caused due to list being mutable, converting `subset` to **tuple**(which is immutable) will help solve the problem. This can be done simply by changing `result.append(subset)` to `result.append(tuple(subset))`.

Finally, if you really want your `result` to have `list` instead of tuples, you can use `results.append(list(tuple(subset)))`. This will create a lit from tuple, which will not have any relation to `subset` hence no hazard, due to mutability, will take place.

**Extra-** You might want to initialize `result` as `result=[]` instead of `result=[[]]`. As in later case it adds an extra empty list in your list of lists.:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to produce all sublists of a given list:

```
list = [1,2,3]

def subset(i):
    finallist = []
    for first in range(0,len(i)+1):
        for last in range(first+1,len(i)+1):
            templist = []
            for index in range(first,last):
                templist.append(i[index])
            finallist.append(templist)
    return finallist


print(subset(list))
```

However this does not include [1,3], as this is not a true sublist. To make all possible combinations of a list, see:

[Making all possible combinations of a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371887/making-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-in-python?rq=1)