# Creating all possible combinations from two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, iterable

I'm trying to think of an efficient way of solving the following problem:

Given any two arrays 'a' and 'b' I'd like to create all lists of combinations, each combination should contain tuples of one element from 'a' and one element from 'b'

for example:

```
a = ['p', 'q'], b = [True, False]
```

the output should be the following:

```
[{'p': False, 'q': False}, {'p': False, 'q': True}, {'p': True, 'q': 
False}, {'p': True, 'q': True}]
```

Comment: can you append in your post the two arrays 'a' and 'b' ?

Comment: I can probably append them, there are no real restrictions, I'm just looking for efficiency

Comment: You are looking for an implementation or using a module?

Comment: anything goes really, as long as it works and is efficient.. I've got a working implementation but It's like... O(n^3).. I think it should be doable in O(n^2)

Comment: You're looking for the [itertools library](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), I don't think you'll find anything more efficient in python

Comment: I've been trying to maybe use the product function from that library.
but I can't figure out a way to make what I want without having to iterate over the product and removing the repeated values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making all possible combinations of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371887/making-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list)

Comment: @ItamarMushkin he want dict not array

Comment: What you'r showing is no a tuple, but an array of dict

Comment: @ItamarMushkin sadly no, this would leave me with the same problem as before. I'd have to weed out the bad combinations that I don't need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import product

dicts = [{k:v for k,v in zip(keys, tup)} for tup in list(product(values, repeat=len(keys)))]
```

Comment: OP - note that this answer does not rely on knowing that the lengths are both 2!

Comment: This does the job. however it does assume the amount of values and keys should be the same, sadly I can have more keys than values

Comment: @edanpatt i updated my answer, it doesn't require equal lengths now

Answer (score 4):

Hey you can use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with `repeat=2`

Here is a working example which builds a list of dictionaries

```
[{k1:v1, k2:v2} for k1,v1,k2,v2 in itertools.product(a,b,repeat=2) if k1 != k2]
```

Comment: I will add though that this solution takes the length being 2 in to account
What I gave was an example. a can be of any length, b in my case can be of just length 2 but I'd like to assume a general case

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['p', 'q']

b = [True, False]
import itertools
result = [{values[0]: values[1]} for values in list(itertools.product(a,b))]

print(result)
```

is that what you need?

Comment: It's a decent start but no, after doing this you'd have to create every possible combination of he dictionaries this function creates

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product
lst = [dict(zip(a,pair)) for pair in product(b,b)]
```

Output:

```
[{'p': True, 'q': True},
 {'p': True, 'q': False},
 {'p': False, 'q': True},
 {'p': False, 'q': False}]
```

EDIT:

Since you say `a` can be of any length, in that case you don't really need `b`.

```
from itertools import permutations
import numpy as np

a = ['p','q','r','s','t']
list1 = list(permuations(a))
set1 = {tuple(np.array(a) == np.array(i)) for i in list1}
final_list = [dict(zip(a,i)) for i in set1]
```

Output:

```
[{'p': True, 'q': False, 'r': False, 's': False, 't': False},
 {'p': True, 'q': False, 'r': True, 's': True, 't': False},
 {'p': False, 'q': False, 'r': False, 's': False, 't': True},
 {'p': True, 'q': False, 'r': True, 's': False, 't': False},
 {'p': False, 'q': False, 'r': True, 's': True, 't': True},
 {'p': True, 'q': False, 'r': False, 's': True, 't': False},
 {'p': False, 'q': False, 'r': False, 's': True, 't': True},
 {'p': False, 'q': False, 'r': True, 's': False, 't': True},
 {'p': False, 'q': True, 'r': False, 's': False, 't': False},
 {'p': False, 'q': True, 'r': True, 's': True, 't': False},
 {'p': False, 'q': True, 'r': False, 's': True, 't': False},
 {'p': False, 'q': True, 'r': True, 's': False, 't': False},
 {'p': True, 'q': True, 'r': True, 's': False, 't': False},
 {'p': True, 'q': True, 'r': False, 's': True, 't': False},
 {'p': True, 'q': True, 'r': False, 's': False, 't': False},
 {'p': True, 'q': True, 'r': False, 's': False, 't': True},
 {'p': True, 'q': False, 'r': False, 's': True, 't': True},
 {'p': True, 'q': False, 'r': True, 's': False, 't': True},
 {'p': False, 'q': False, 'r': False, 's': True, 't': False},
 {'p': False, 'q': False, 'r': True, 's': False, 't': False},
 {'p': True, 'q': False, 'r': False, 's': False, 't': True},
 {'p': False, 'q': False, 'r': False, 's': False, 't': False},
 {'p': False, 'q': False, 'r': True, 's': True, 't': False},
 {'p': False, 'q': True, 'r': False, 's': True, 't': True},
 {'p': False, 'q': True, 'r': True, 's': False, 't': True},
 {'p': True, 'q': True, 'r': True, 's': True, 't': True},
 {'p': False, 'q': True, 'r': False, 's': False, 't': True}]
```