# Find all ways to decide list into three

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, combinations

Like the title says, how can I find all of the ways a list can be divided into three lists? For example 1,2,3 would return

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1] [2] [3]
[1, 2] [3] [ ]
[1] [2, 3] [ ]
[1, 3] [2] [ ]
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff but just can't seem to get it. Thanks!

Comment: should [1, 2, 3] [ ] [ ] also be an answer?

Comment: @wkzhu it should my bad

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making all possible combinations of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371887/making-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list)

Answer (score 2):

you could use `combinations` from the lib `itertools`

```
import itertools

my_list = [1, 2, 3]

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    print(list(itertools.combinations(my_list, i + 1)))
```

which outputs

```
[(1,), (2,), (3,)]
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
[(1, 2, 3)]
```

now you can add the length of each list and add the missing empty lists (to complete having 3 lists) and voila - you have your result

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
import itertools

# your input data list
a = [1, 2, 3]

# util function to convert list of tuples to list of list
f = lambda x: [list(i) if isinstance(i, tuple) else i for i in x]

# list1 is all combinations of sublists having length = 1,2,..length_of_a from input list `a` and empty list [] 
list1 = []
for i in range(1, len(a)+1):
    list1.extend(itertools.combinations(a, i))
list1.extend([()]*(len(a)-1))

# list2 is all combinations of sublists having length = length_of_a from the list1
list2 = list(set(itertools.combinations(list1, len(a))))

#  filtering out and converting list of tuples for the final results
results = [f(i) for i in list2 if sum(itertools.chain(*i)) == sum(a) and set(itertools.chain(*i)) == set(a)]
results.append(a)

# print out the results
for r in results:
    print(r)
```

Outputs:

[[1, 2, 3], [], []]

[[3], [1, 2], []]

[[1], [2], [3]]

[[2], [1, 3], []]

[[1], [2, 3], []]

[1, 2, 3]