# Python: find all combinations of elements in list to reach a certain value

Tags: python

I'm given a list, for example: `[2,5,8]` and a value `c`, for example, 33.
So, because the length of the list is `3`, I have to return a list of tuples `(i,j,k)` for which `i*w[0] + j*w[1] + k*w[2] == c (33)`.

Of course, this is easily solved with 3 for loops, as shown:

```
res = []
for i in range(c+1):
   for j in range(c+1):
       for g in range(c+1):
           if i*self.w[0] + j*self.w[1] + g*self.w[2] == c:
              res.append((i,j,g))
return sorted(res)
```

The output will be:

```
[(0, 5, 1), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (4, 5, 0), (5, 3, 1), (6, 1, 2), (9, 3, 0), (10, 1, 1), (14, 1, 0)]
```

The problem is that I have to do this with lists with other lengths as well. So my question is; does anyone know how to do this in general, for a list with length `x` (not too big) and a given value `c`?

Comment: looks like your question might be related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371887/making-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making all possible combinations of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371887/making-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.product` and `operator.mul`:

```
>>> [k for k in product(range(c+1), repeat=len(w)) if sum(map(mul, w, k)) == c]
[(0, 5, 1), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (4, 5, 0), (5, 3, 1), (6, 1, 2), (9, 3, 0), (10, 1, 1), (14, 1, 0)]
```

Comment: Nice. I hadn't realised that `map` can take more than one iterable. That's another useful thing you've taught me today.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I was wondering if you know how to do this without using itertools and map because we didn't learn that at school so we're not allowed to use that kind of tools

Comment: @StijnOosterlinck Then perhaps recursion. Or, depending on the data specification, dynamic programming.

Comment: hmm okay maybe its useful to understand this code because it simplifies the problem a lot, can you explain a little bit more what you're doing in the oneliner?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.product` and `zip` to generalise here:

```
import itertools
w = [3,1,2,5]
c = 33
l = [range(c + 1)] * len(w)
res = []
for values in itertools.product(*l):
    if sum(a * b for a, b in zip(w, values)) == c:
        res.append(values)
print(sorted(res))
```

The loop that builds up `res` could be replaced by a list comprehension if desired.  That is to say:

```
￼res = [values for values in itertools.product(*l)
           if sum(a * b for a, b in zip(w, values)) == c]
```