# Most effient way to find all combinations of elements in a long list Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, out-of-memory, combinations, long-integer

Sorry the title looks a little far-fetched. I was asked to calculate the sum of 2 or more elements in a list. I searched it up on the web, I found some results, I tested them, but it didn't work...

input.txt

```
35
20
15
25
47
40
62
55
65
95
102
117
150
182
127
219
299
277
309
576
```

code.py

```
from itertools import combinations
  
def combo(arr, r):
  return list(combinations(arr, r))

with open("input.txt") as f:
  nums = f.read().split("\n")
  nums = [int(item) for item in nums]

r = range(2,20)
for rr in r:
  for c in combo(nums, rr):
    if sum(c) == 127:
        print(c)
```

It works in the code above, it works because the list is quite short. However, the `input.txt` I recieved was 100 lines long! In that case, Python threw a MemoryError. So I needed to find a better way. Unfortunately, I didn't find any other way, except a longer way, so I ask the question, "What is the most effient way to find the combination of elements in a long list in Python".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to save memory by not converting the output of `itertools.combinations` to a list and instead just iterating over the generator output:

```
for rr in range(2, 22):
    print(f"combine {rr} values")
    for c in itertools.combinations(values, rr):
        if sum(c) == 127:
            print(c)
```

Check: [Making all possible combinations of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371887/making-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list)