# Improved way to get subsets of a list

Tags: python, algorithm

The following is how I'm getting subsets of a list:

```
def subsets(s):
    if not s: return [[]]
    rest = subsets(s[1:])
    return rest + map(lambda x: [s[0]] + x, rest)

x = sorted(subsets([1,2,3]), key=lambda x: (len(x), x))
# [[], [1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

It works, but is a bit slow. I'm wondering what might be a better less-naive algorithm to get all subsets in python (without just using something like [`itertools.combinations`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371887/making-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list)).

Comment: "without just using something" that was specifically designed to do exactly that job. What's the point?

Comment: To be explicit, your function `subsets` actually returns the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of `s` (which *is* the set of all subsets, so you're not wrong), which has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1482316/11659881) using `itertools.chain` and `itertools.combinations`. Clearly, you're looking for something better but I felt this was worth mentioning.

Comment: @user3386109 to learn, to improve my own algorithms, etc. etc.

Comment: Then you should post on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), because that's what code review is for.

Comment: maybe writing a dict that stores len as key and subsets as value?

Comment: The main thing I don't like about this code is that you're returning a list instead of a generator, so it'll get big in memory fast.

Comment: What version of Python are you using, by the way? I can a this error trying to run your code: `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "map") to list`.

Comment: @joanis I think you can wrap the `map` in a `list(map)` and it should fix that for python3.

Comment: Right, I figured that out after asking. Thanks! I keep forgetting that lots of things return lists in Python 2 but generators in Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much more efficient to avoid storing the list of subsets in memory unless you actually need it.

#### Solution 1: return a generator as output

This code accomplishes that with a recursive generator function:

```py
def subsets(s):
    if not s:
        yield []
    else:
        for x in subsets(s[1:]):
            yield x
            yield [s[0]] + x
```

This function will lazily do its work only as required by the caller and never stores more than just the call stack in memory.

The first `yield` in the `else` clause serves to yield all elements of `subsets(s[1:])` unchanged, i.e., those subsets of `s` that don't include `s[0]`, while the second one yields all the subsets of `s` that do include `s[0]`.

Of course, if you want this list sorted, the efficiency is lost when you call `sorted()` on the results, which builds the list in memory.

#### Solution 2: also accept a generator or an iterator as input

Solution 1 has the weakness that it only works on indexable `s` types, like lists and tuples, where `s[0]` and `s[1:]` are well defined.

If we want to make `subsets` more generic and accept any iterable (including iterators), we have to avoid that syntax and use `next()` instead:

```py
def subsets(s):
    iterator = iter(s)
    try:
        item = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        # s in empty, bottom out of the recursion
        yield []
    else:
        # s is not empty, recurse and expand
        for x in subsets(iterator):
            yield x
            yield [item] + x
```

#### Measuring performance

With all this, I wanted to know how much difference these solutions make, so I ran some benchmarks.

I compared your initial code, which I'm calling `subsets_lists`, my solution1, `subsets_generator` here, my solution2, `subsets_gen_iterable`. For completeness, I added the [`powerset` function suggested in itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

###### Results:

All subsets of a list of size 10, each call repeated 10 times:

```
Code block 'l = subsets_lists(range(10)) repeats=10' took: 5.58828 ms
Code block 'g = subsets_generator(range(10)) repeats=10' took: 0.05693 ms
Code block 'g = subsets_gen_iterable(range(10)) repeats=10' took: 0.01316 ms
Code block 'l = list(subsets_generator(range(10))) repeats=10' took: 4.86464 ms
Code block 'l = list(subsets_gen_iterable(range(10))) repeats=10' took: 3.76597 ms
Code block 'l = list(powerset(range(10))) size=10 repeats=10' took: 1.11228 ms
```

All subsets of a list of size 20, each call repeated 10 times:

```
Code block 'l = subsets_lists(range(20)) repeats=10' took: 12144.99487 ms
Code block 'g = subsets_generator(range(20)) repeats=10' took: 65.18992 ms
Code block 'g = subsets_gen_iterable(range(20)) repeats=10' took: 0.01784 ms
Code block 'l = list(subsets_generator(range(20))) repeats=10' took: 10859.75128 ms
Code block 'l = list(subsets_gen_iterable(range(20))) repeats=10' took: 10074.26618 ms
Code block 'l = list(powerset(range(20))) size=20 repeats=10' took: 2336.81373 ms
```

###### Observations:

- You can see that calling the two generator functions does not do much work unless the generators are fed into something that consumes it, like the `list()` constructor. Although `subsets_generator` does seem to do a lot more work up front than `subsets_gen_iterable`.
- My two solutions yield modest speed improvements over your code
- The `itertools`-based solution is still much faster.

###### Actual benchmarking code:

```py
import itertools
import linetimer

def subsets_lists(s):
    if not s: return [[]]
    rest = subsets_lists(s[1:])
    return rest + list(map(lambda x: [s[0]] + x, rest))

def subsets_generator(s):
    if not s:
        yield []
    else:
        for x in subsets_generator(s[1:]):
            yield x
            yield [s[0]] + x

def subsets_iterable(s):
    iterator = iter(s)
    try:
        item = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        yield []
    else:
        for x in subsets_iterable(iterator):
            yield x
            yield [item] + x

def powerset(iterable):
    "Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes"
    s = list(iterable)
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        itertools.combinations(s, r)
        for r in range(len(s)+1)
    )

for repeats in 1, 10:
    for size in 4, 10, 14, 20:
        with linetimer.CodeTimer(f"l = subsets_lists(range({size})) repeats={repeats}"):
            for _ in range(repeats):
                l = subsets_lists(range(size))
        with linetimer.CodeTimer(f"g = subsets_generator(range({size})) repeats={repeats}"):
            for _ in range(repeats):
                l = subsets_generator(range(size))
        with linetimer.CodeTimer(f"g = subsets_gen_iterable(range({size})) repeats={repeats}"):
            for _ in range(repeats):
                l = subsets_iterable(range(size))
        with linetimer.CodeTimer(f"l = list(subsets_generator(range({size}))) repeats={repeats}"):
            for _ in range(repeats):
                l = list(subsets_generator(range(size)))
        with linetimer.CodeTimer(f"l = list(subsets_gen_iterable(range({size}))) repeats={repeats}"):
            for _ in range(repeats):
                l = list(subsets_iterable(range(size)))
        with linetimer.CodeTimer(f"l = list(powerset(range({size}))) size={size} repeats={repeats}"):
            for _ in range(repeats):
                l = list(powerset(range(size)))
```

Comment: thanks, why do you do two `yields` in the `else` branch?

Comment: It's my equivalent of your `rest` concatenated to `map(lambda x: [s[0]] + x, rest)`. The first yield yields the next element of `subsets(s[1:])`, i.e., subsets where `s[0]` is not included, while the second one yields that element with `s[0]` prepended, i.e., subsets where `s[0]` is included.