# All possible group pairings using all the elements in the list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string like "12345" I need to make alp possible groups using the whole string. It should be something loke this. "12345" becomes [1, 2345], [12, 345]... [1234, 5], [12345]. In between these main headings I also need to consider pairs like [1,2, 34, 5], [12, 34, 5]. I figured these come by further splitting the [1] element. Like [1234,5] is also transformable as [12, 3,4,5].
In short using all the elements of a group to make 1 combination. get all such possible group combinations .
My code:

```
final_list = {}
ex = ''
def get_all_comb(integer_string):
    for ele in range(1, len(integer_string) + 1):
        temp_1 = integer_string[:ele]
        temp_2 = integer_string[ele:]

        final_list[temp_1] = get_all_comb_helper(temp_2)

    return final_list


def get_all_comb_helper(integer_string):
    all_list = []
    for ele in range(1, len(integer_string) + 1):
        temp_1 = integer_string[:ele]
        temp_2 = integer_string[ele:]
        list_x = [temp_1,temp_2]
        all_list.append(list_x)

    return all_list

print(get_all_comb("12345")
```

Output:
`{'i': [['2', '345'], ['23', '45'], ['234', '5'], ['2345', '']], 'i2': [['3', '45'], ['34', '5'], ['345', '']], 'i23': [['4', '5'], ['45', '']], 'i234': [['5', '']], 'i2345': []}`

If you understood the question. Please help me. Time complexity is also an issue, went through itertools and found that accumulate does such a thing but only achieve the first line. Please suggest a method or a tool to do this o[eeatipn.

I tried itertools.Combinations and itertools.accumilate. I also tried a for loop where the iterator takes :index for one sub group amd index: for its corresponding remainder. I tried recursion on the remainder element to get the answer but it also has other possibilities in it and too random to clean up. Please help

Comment: How is this different from [Making all possible combinations of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8371891/5763413)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making all possible combinations of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371887/making-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list)

Comment: this question is a duplicate.

Comment: @blackbrandt No this doesn't answer my question. The question is to get all combinations without changing the order. 12345 can only be written as 1 ,2345 or 1, 2, 3, 45 etc.  Not 13254 etc.